# PHP extra whitespace not being deleted

Tags: php, regex

I'm counting words in an article and removing common words such as "and" or "the".
I"m removing them by use of preg_replace

after it is done I do a quick clean of extra white space by using.

```
$search_body = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$search_body);
```

However I've got some very stubborn white space that will not go away. I've tried

```
if($word == "" OR $word == " "){
  //chop it's head off
}
```

But the if statement does not see $word as being just whitespace. I've also tried printing it to the screen to get the raw data type of it and it's still just showing up blank.

Here is the full regex that I'm using.

```
$pattern = array(   
        '/\&quot\;/',
        '/[0-9]/',
        '/\,/',
        '/\./',
        '/\!/',
        '/\@/',
        '/\#/',
        '/\$/',
        '/\%/',
        '/\^/',
        '/\&/',
        '/\*/',
        '/\(/',
        '/\)/',
        '/\_/',
        '/\"/',
        '/\'/',
        '/\:/',
        '/\;/',
        '/\?/',
        '/\`/',
        '/\~/',
        '/\[/',
        '/\]/',
        '/\{/',
        '/\}/',
        '/\|/',
        '/\+/',
        '/\=/',
        '/\-/',
        '/–/',
        '/°/',
        '/\bthe\b/',
        '/\band\b/',
        '/\bthat\b/',
        '/\bhave\b/',
        '/\bfor\b/',
        '/\bnot\b/',
        '/\bwith\b/',
        '/\byou\b/',
        '/\bthis\b/',
        '/\bbut\b/',
        '/\bhis\b/',
        '/\bfrom\b/',
        '/\bthey\b/',
        '/\bsay\b/',
        '/\bher\b/',
        '/\bshe\b/',
        '/\bwill\b/',
        '/\bone\b/',
        '/\ball\b/',
        '/\bwould\b/',
        '/\bthere\b/',
        '/\btheir\b/',
        '/\bwhat\b/',
        '/\bout\b/',
        '/\babout\b/',
        '/\bwho\b/',
        '/\bget\b/',
        '/\bwhich\b/',
        '/\bwhen\b/',
        '/\bmake\b/',
        '/\bcan\b/',
        '/\blike\b/',
        '/\btime\b/',
        '/\bjust\b/',
        '/\bhim\b/',
        '/\bknow\b/',
        '/\btake\b/',
        '/\bpeople\b/',
        '/\binto\b/',
        '/\byear\b/',
        '/\byour\b/',
        '/\bgood\b/',
        '/\bsome\b/',
        '/\bcould\b/',
        '/\bthem\b/',
        '/\bsee\b/',
        '/\bother\b/',
        '/\bthan\b/',
        '/\bthen\b/',
        '/\bnow\b/',
        '/\blook\b/',
        '/\bonly\b/',
        '/\bcome\b/',
        '/\bits\b/', //it's?
        '/\bover\b/',
        '/\bthink\b/',
        '/\balso\b/',
        '/\bback\b/',
        '/\bafter\b/',
        '/\buse\b/',
        '/\btwo\b/',
        '/\bhow\b/',
        '/\bour\b/',
        '/\bwork\b/',
        '/\bfirst\b/',
        '/\bwell\b/',
        '/\bway\b/',
        '/\beven\b/',
        '/\bnew\b/',
        '/\bwant\b/',
        '/\bbecause\b/',
        '/\bany\b/',
        '/\bthese\b/',
        '/\bgive\b/',
        '/\bday\b/',
        '/\bmost\b/',
        '/\bare\b/',
        '/\bwas\b/',
        '/\<\w+\>/', '/\<\/\w+\>/',
        '/\b\w{1}\b/', //1 letter word
        '/\b\w{2}\b/', //2 letter word
        '/\//',
        '/\</',       
        '/\>/'
        );

$search_body    = strip_tags($body);
$search_body    = strtolower($search_body);
$search_body    = preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $search_body);
$search_body    = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$search_body);
$search_body    = explode(" ", $search_body);
```

When exploded blank values show up left and right

Example text that I am using is too long to post here. But I copied and pasted
[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stainless_steel) to give it a test and it showed 32 counts of white space, not including the white space in front of or behind of other words even after using trim().

[Here's a js.fiddle of the raw data that is being handled by php.](http://jsfiddle.net/nkvovogx/)

htmlentities and htmlspecialchars also show nothing.

Here's the code counts all the values and puts them into one.

```
$inhere     = array();
$body_hold  = array();
foreach($search_body as $value){
  $value = trim($value);
  if(in_array($value, $inhere) && $value != ""){
    $key = array_search($value, $inhere);
    $body_hold[$key]['count'] = $body_hold[$key]['count']+1;
  }elseif($value != ""){
    $inhere[] = $value;
    $body_hold[] = array(
      'count'  => 1,
      'word'   => $value
    );
  }
}
rsort($body_hold);
```

Basic foreach to see values.

```
foreach($body_hold as $value){
  $count  = $value['count'];
  $word   = trim($value['word']);
  echo "Count: ".$count;
  echo " Word: ".$word;
  echo '<br>';
}
```

[Here's a PHP example of what it's returning](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59fd8e4826d5d98506ed69e6226ce9fe7427baf2)

Comment: Could it be that these are actually `\r\n` for instance?

Comment: Thats expected ? All of the replacements will be in the explode ?

Comment: @exussum Right, but my problem is, why didn't the regex catch and remove it and why can't my if else statements catch it either?

Comment: Add this regex: `/(?:\r|\n|\r\n|&nbsp;)/`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thanks, I tried this but had no luck. I put it in the first regex and then a seperate one after the regex just to be certain.

Comment: @derp I Posted the raw data that I'm sending with PHP on js.fiddle but I don't know of any websites that I can make a replica with PHP.

Comment: To add to @derp comment, you can also use http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ to run and save your code. I'm not exactly sure of what you are trying to achieve but the code seems overly complicated. Can you try to give a small example that doesn't go well and the expected result?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I'm trying to make a related articles section, but first I'd like to remove all of the unimporant characters. Here's  the exact code that I have giving me the exact results. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59fd8e4826d5d98506ed69e6226ce9fe7427baf2

Comment: @TrevorW The whitespace is the `&nbsp;` i told you in the last regex. But, it's processed already. Here is all about it: http://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/

Comment: @TrevorW Add this to your regex list: `'/'."\xc2\xa0".'/'`. It works **PERFECTLY**! Check here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db443201638f383b9653c0ba42ad5010b4e8a2ff Or you can make it pretty like `"@\xc2\xa0@"` (untested)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Worked perfectly, Thank you. If you post your answer I'll give it a check for other people who also have this issue. Also I clicked the link, but I didn't see where or how you found the answer to be '/'."\xc2\xa0".'/'

Comment: @TrevorW I did like this: I went to the site I gave to you, then I used this code: `for($i=0,$l=strlen($s='<put the &nbsp; here>';$i<$l;++$i)echo dechex(ord($s[$i]));` which gave me `c2a0`. Then I added `\x` in front of each pair, resulting in `\xc2\xa0`. Since PHP sees a utf8 char as a set of multiple chars, then this will succeed. You must use `""` or an heredoc or this won't work!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you put the exact same data you're processing in the js.fiddle? Or did you get it from a subsequent post-processed step?

It's obviously a Wikipedia article. I went to that article on Wikipedia and opened it in Edit mode, and saw that there are &nbsp;s in the raw wikitext. However, those nbsp's don't appear in your js.fiddle data.

TL;DR: Check for &nbsp; in your processing (and convert to spaces, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This character 160 looks like space but it's not, replacing all of them to the regular spaces (32) and then removing all the double spaces will fix your problem.

```
$search_body = str_replace(chr(160), chr(32), $search_body);
$search_body = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $search_body));
```